# Golang, fatal error: out of memory on 1 TB RAM machine

Tags: memory, go, out-of-memory

I have a code with a huge `uint8` slice of nearly 590 million elements. I'm keeping this array in the code to make it run as fast as possible. The code's final size is 1.3 GB.

When I try to compile it, it raises the `fatal error: out of memory`. with following

```
# command-line-arguments
fatal error: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x8fb3f2, 0xd)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x7f5c2afa3ba8, 0x1440000000a, 0x7f57dc46d5e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:123 +0x160
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:505 +0x33
runtime.systemstack(0xc420044000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0x131f300c970 sp=0x131f300c968
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x7f5c2afa3ba8, 0xa, 0x0, 0x131f300ca80, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:506 +0xb2 fp=0x131f300c9c8 sp=0x131f300c970
runtime.mallocgc(0x90, 0x8ed060, 0x1, 0x115f3f9c)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:658 +0x809 fp=0x131f300ca68 sp=0x131f300c9c8
runtime.newobject(0x8ed060, 0xe00b46a450)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:785 +0x38 fp=0x131f300ca98 sp=0x131f300ca68
cmd/compile/internal/gc.Nod(0xd6c186c643, 0xfca1028090, 0xd6c186c480, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/subr.go:335 +0x31 fp=0x131f300cac0 sp=0x131f300ca98
cmd/compile/internal/gc.arraylit(0x0, 0x1, 0xc420663290, 0xfca1028090, 0x131f300d6c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/sinit.go:698 +0x18f fp=0x131f300cb48 sp=0x131f300cac0
cmd/compile/internal/gc.slicelit(0x0, 0xc420663290, 0xfca1018000, 0x131f300d6c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/sinit.go:765 +0xb36 fp=0x131f300cc58 sp=0x131f300cb48
cmd/compile/internal/gc.anylit(0x0, 0xc420663290, 0xfca1018000, 0x131f300d6c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/sinit.go:1106 +0xac3 fp=0x131f300cd30 sp=0x131f300cc58
cmd/compile/internal/gc.oaslit(0xfca1017ef0, 0x131f300d6c0, 0xfca1018000)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/sinit.go:1192 +0x104 fp=0x131f300cd60 sp=0x131f300cd30
cmd/compile/internal/gc.walkexpr(0xfca1017ef0, 0x131f300d6c0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go:725 +0xe9c fp=0x131f300d5b8 sp=0x131f300cd60
cmd/compile/internal/gc.walkstmt(0xfca1017ef0, 0xfca1018090)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go:192 +0xf45 fp=0x131f300d7f0 sp=0x131f300d5b8
cmd/compile/internal/gc.walkstmtlist(0x131f3184000, 0x21, 0x40)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go:80 +0x4d fp=0x131f300d820 sp=0x131f300d7f0
cmd/compile/internal/gc.walk(0xc42065ccf0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/walk.go:65 +0x1e4 fp=0x131f300d8f0 sp=0x131f300d820
cmd/compile/internal/gc.compile(0xc42065ccf0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/pgen.go:391 +0x1d4 fp=0x131f300dba0 sp=0x131f300d8f0
cmd/compile/internal/gc.funccompile(0xc42065ccf0)
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/dcl.go:1287 +0x186 fp=0x131f300dc18 sp=0x131f300dba0
cmd/compile/internal/gc.Main()
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/main.go:467 +0x19f8 fp=0x131f300de60 sp=0x131f300dc18
cmd/compile/internal/amd64.Main()
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/amd64/galign.go:93 +0x2fa fp=0x131f300de98 sp=0x131f300de60
main.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/cmd/compile/main.go:33 +0x2a3 fp=0x131f300df28 sp=0x131f300de98
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:183 +0x1f4 fp=0x131f300df80 sp=0x131f300df28
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0x131f300df88 sp=0x131f300df80
```

I think the machine's RAM is enough for this kind of task but couldn't pass this issue. I tried the code with another slice of 21 million elements and it works fine with it. It's a really hard computation task, and since it needed to be running really fast, I cannot use an external file for data.

Already optimized the variable types.

Any ideas?

Comment: This smells of passing too many things by value or too many pointers (remember that a pointer is 8x the size of a data element here, so careful how you're passing things around).  Suggest using a profiler to figure out where your bad passage is happening.  https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: I don't even use pointers other than taking command line arguments. Just lots of computations and slice operations. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Oh, and if you're doing a ton of append() without preallocation, you're forcing the heap to do a ton of work (reallocating/recopying over and over). See if preallocating all your entries in advance helps (like "make([]uint8, 10000000000)" or something).

Comment: are you using go1.7?

Comment: @JimB dude machine has 1 TB of RAM already, who has more than that? Yes it's 1.7.

Comment: @BJBlack, this is during compilation.

Comment: @BJ Black I agree with JimB, I don't do any calculation or appending before getting the arguments from command line which I cannot take before compile as nature of my code.

Comment: It shouldn't be the *only* thing getting in your way since you still have nowhere near 1 TB worth of data, but have you tried declaring your constant as an array instead of as a slice, e.g. `myArray := [...]uint8 {` instead of `mySlice := []uint8 {`? This would tell the compiler that you want a backing array to hold *exactly* that much data, and there's no need to reserve any extra or optimize for the possibility that you'll be appending to it. Since anything that consumes your data will probably still expect a slice, you can convert from an array to a slice with `myArray[:]`.

Comment: @Jesse Amano I will try that and let you know asap. Thanks.

Comment: Man, you're right.  It's compile-time; I missed that.  That's weird.  How are you pulling the data into the program?  Are you compiling the dataset into the binary or something?

Comment: @BJ Black It's just a slice in code, like `slice := []uint8{2,3,4,2,3,4,5...}` (millions of elements).

Comment: Ouch.  So that's why the compiler was freaking out.  It has to track a ton of data about each identifier (not just the parse tree, but a bunch of intra-object links) so I can totally imagine what's up.  And the runtime linker won't be super happy at runtime either.  Why not read this at program start from a binary file again?  Do you have some single-monolithic-file requirement?

Comment: The alternative I suppose would be to shard the data into multiple packages (I.e. "package data1" in data1.go, "package data2" in data2.go, etc, then pulling them all in your main at runtime), so the compiler need only carry part of the data at any one time.  Or try linking that as a C object and doing something really weird with objcopy.  Either way, yuck.

Comment: @BJ Black Can you please provide an example about how to read this at program start from a binary file?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm away from my PC for a couple of hours; will do as soon as I'm back.

Comment: Ok, I'm waiting for that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the (binary) data in a file, you should be able to read it into your slice. Open the file with `os.Open` and then call `io.ReadFull` on that and your slice.

Comment: `String literals`  maybe help you reduce the source size(using character for printable, and \x for others not printable). converting string to []byte at runtime.

Comment: Try:  http://pastebin.com/pVgRbris (updated to []uint8 instead of []byte)

This uses good ol' ioutil.ReadFile to slurp in all the data at runtime.  Ran in about 200ms on my i5-based laptop with a 500 MiB binary of random bytes.

Comment: Jiang:  Careful with that; strings are UTF-8 by default, so figuring out what's printable and what's not (and what's an invalid sequence) is tricky.  Better to slurp in as a []byte and convert to []uint8 as in my pastbin.

Comment: Other options are using something like [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) with the `-nomemcpy` flag to pack the data into the binary (nor sure how it will handle this data size though), or append your data to the binary and access it via a zip archive (examples here, but looks unmaintained https://github.com/cookieo9/resources-go/tree/v2.1). It's really just easier to load the data from an external source.

Comment: @Jesse Amano it's not working unfortunately but thanks anyway.

Comment: @BJ Black this doesn't read the bin file as a slice that similar to the slice that I was using, it has different format and the code is not working properly with it. Trying to handle this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @BJ Black it's working now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the data from external binary file as bytes. The following code @BJ Black provided helped.

```
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile("somefile.bin")
    if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }
    // Coerce type
    uintbuf := []uint8(buf)
```

Comment: BTW, byte is completely equivalent to uint8 in any way according to docs - https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#byte

Comment: @tez Yes, I know but I just wanted to include the code that helped me without editing it. Thanks.